# Using conda environment at a specific directory

Tags: python, conda, virtual-environment

as a research group, we would like to use a common conda environment in which we will install the common packages. We'd like to do this in a cluster/supercomputer.

What I couldn't find any information about is that how we can use an environment which is in a specific directory, in other words, how we can activate an environment which is in a specific directory.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the docs? *"To activate an environment: `conda activate myenv` Replace `myenv` with the environment name or directory path."* - [Managing environments § Activating an environment](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment)

Comment: Yes, I think I missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tips for shared (centralized) named environments

I provide shared environments for students in a computational biology course where most of the assignments involve using an HPC. Some suggestions:

1. **Create a dedicated folder** for the shared environments (say `/shared/conda_envs`). For a class, this folder is `r-x`-only for students; for a research group, that's up to you, but I'd still do the same and have one person with the lab job of creating new environments who has write permissions (could be you).
2. Have users **add the folder to the Conda configuration**. This should be *appended*, so they don't default to creating environments there:

   ```
   conda config --append envs_dirs /shared/conda_envs
   ```

   This allows users to reference the environments *by name* rather than by prefix.
3. **Create environments in copy-mode**. This avoids any linking back to the creating user's package cache.

   ```
   CONDA_ALWAYS_COPY=1 mamba env create -f env1.yaml -p /shared/conda_envs/env1
   ```